# What does 0 vector means for these vectors in part C?

Tags: calculus

[image]

I did part a and b but for part c does the fact that when those three vectors are added gives the zero vector does it mean that they are all perpendicular to eachother? So therefore they would all have the same cross product?

Comment: No, they are not all perpendicular to each other.  The three vectors are the sides of a triangle.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply I´m just confused as to why in part b the cross products are the same?

Comment: You have the 3 points - draw the image, it will help. Remember what the magnitude of the cross product is?

Comment: The cross product is a vector that is perpendicular to two other vectors and in this question I got [1,-14,10]. Also

Comment: What @FilipMilovanović said.  What is the geometric interpretation of the cross product?  Not only the direction (perpendicular) but the magnitude.

Comment: Oh sorry, so the magnitude of the cross product would be the area of a parallelogram.

Answer (score 1):

One half of the module of each of the three cross products represent the area of the same triangle. Because of the order of the vectors in the product for each case, the direction is also the same.